# How to use an alias in a sql join

Tags: sql, alias, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I create a variable with a case when like it:

```
case  when (a.exit_date='0001-01-01' and z.fermeture<>'0001-01-01') then z.fermeture
else a.exit_date
 end as final_exit_date,
```

And after I got a sql join like it:

```
select a.*,b.*

from   table1 as a
  left join table2 as b on (a.id=b.id and b.start <= a.exit_date and a.exit_date < b.end)

where a.id=28445
```

When I do it, it works ! But me I don't want use the variable "a.exit_date"
I want replace it per the variable that I created ( final_exit_date), like it:

```
select a.*,b.*

from   table1 as a
  left join table2 as b on (a.id = b.id and b.start <= final_exit_date and final_exit_date < b.end)

where a.id=28445
```

Thanks in advance for reading me !!

Comment: You haven't created a "variable".  You have added a column to a result set.  You can use a CTE or subquery to access it in the `on` clause.

Comment: the case statement does not exist when the DB is processing the joins. You'll need to create a sub-query (or common table expression CTE as @GordonLinoff suggested) where the variable is defined along with the any additional columns from the  "a" table and then join b table to the sub-query instead of directly to "a"

Comment: ahh ok thanks, so how can I do it with a CTE or subquery exactely pls ?

Comment: it would be something like b.start <=   (select case when ...)  ???

Comment: There is a documentation https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/queries-cte.html for CTE in Snowflake

Comment: thx, I will try with it !

Answer (score 1):

When you create an expression with an alias in a `SELECT` list, the only place you are allowed to use the alias is in the `ORDER BY` clause. This frustrates many people in SQL because it is often that the alias would be useful in a `WHERE` clause or elsewhere, but that is not possible.

The solution is that you have to duplicate the expression instead of using the alias.

```sql
SELECT a.*,b.*
FROM table1 AS a
-- you will need the z table as well
LEFT JOIN table2 AS b ON (a.id=b.id and b.start <= 
CASE WHEN (a.exit_date='0001-01-01' AND z.fermeture<>'0001-01-01') THEN z.fermeture ELSE a.exit_date END 
AND 
CASE WHEN (a.exit_date='0001-01-01' AND z.fermeture<>'0001-01-01') THEN z.fermeture ELSE a.exit_date END < b.end)
WHERE a.id=28445
```

Another option is to use a common table expression (CTE) or a subquery so that the alias is available. Using a CTE, it would look something like this:

```sql
;WITH records AS (
    SELECT a.*, CASE WHEN (a.exit_date='0001-01-01' AND z.fermeture<>'0001-01-01') THEN z.fermeture ELSE a.exit_date END AS final_exit_date
    FROM table1 AS a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN otherTable AS z ON a.id = z.id -- whatever the condition is
) 
SELECT r.* b.* 
FROM records AS r 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS b ON r.id = b.id AND b.start<= r.final_exit_date AND r.final_exit_date < b.end
```

There are likely some issues with the query above since you didn't include the table names or the columns (or how they are even related), but you should be able to create a working solution by adapting one of these two approaches.